# C# Merge VOB files, is it possible?

Tags: c#, vob

All,

I'm making a training kit that has content given to use with 2 VOB files that I need the software to automatically merge to 1.  We'll be getting upto 10-15 vob files from this vender and our requirements are to move to a single file.

Is merging these files as easy as opening byte streams and combining them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the specifications of the files match it should be possible to use the header from the first file and copy the remaining files minus their header into one file. But the specifications needs to match exactly on everything from encoding type and parameters to number of audio channels.

If so, then all you need to do is read all the files and skip the first xxx bytes of every file except the first one.

It won't work if the VOB-files are encrypted (DVD encryption).

Note: This is a job specialized tools do well. They are optimized and (more or less) bug free. So if you can, use them (i.e. from the command line).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not simple merging. Otherwise old DOS command `>type 1.VOB, 2.VOB > Final.VOB` would have done the job.

Unless it is for some learning, just use [any VOB merging](http://www.google.co.in/search?aq=0&oq=merging+VOB+file&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=merging+vob+files) tool to merge these two.

Comment: Not to sure you are correct here.  Byte merging 2 files created a file that is playable, just not sure if something else is required.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this is probably going to depend on if the VOB files have the same resolution and bit rate, as well ensuring a lot of other encoding parameters are the same.  If they are using the exact same encoding parameters, simply doing a concatenation of the files will probably work.  My experience with DVDs shows that files from the DVD  work fine when this is done.  However, my first guess is that this wouldn't work if there was any format differences between the files.